# User specified name for an object

Tags: c

Is it possible to assign an  user specified name to an object.
Usually we declare `Sample s;`
Can we accept the object name from user?
That is,to make `Sample <user-defined-obj-name>;`

Comment: Not in C++ as far as i know.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Please tell us why you want to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Object names don't matter to runtime users, they usually aren't even visible.  What is the purpose of the name?  Also, to add to that, who is the user?  The programmer or actual program runner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not possible (directly) in C.  Variable names are a compile-time construct and don't really exist at runtime.  The best you can do is make some kind of associative data structure, and map the user-provided strings to your objects there.

Comment: It's the same in C++.